# How to format numbers in List&Label (by Combit) as power notation?

Tags: report, number-formatting, decimalformat, listlabel

I'm using ***List & Label*** to display results on a report (floats) and I don't want them to be displayed by large numbers of decimal places like:
**0.00005850**
but like:
**5,85e-05**

I would be glad if someone had a hint for me :-) I already tried out the number format settings but nothing suiting there. Excel does this automatically, but is there a way in List&Label at all?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the scientific exponential format works nicely - have you tried this setting?
[image: Exponential Format]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great, @LM358 - you might consider to mark it as answer then :)

Comment: could you also show me a solution for textfields belonging to a table (container)? There I couldn't find "Exponential Format". Can this be solved by using str$(..) function maybe?

Comment: A text field has the same "Format" property that allows you to choose exponential format. Simply doubleclick the report container, then select the text field in the tree on the left hand side. In the field's properties you'll find the "Format" property.